# Set-theoretic solutions of YBE for $n=3$

Tags: co.combinatorics, yang-baxter-equations

Is there a list of all set theoretic solutions $S:X \times X \to X \times X$ of the YBE for $X=\{1,2,3\}$? Or is it known how many solutions there are? I mean, $S_9$ is big but maybe not too big to check it with the computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure,

degenerate solutions:

\begin{equation}
((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3)),
((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3))
\end{equation}

non degenerate solutions:

\begin{equation}
((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 1)),
 ((2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1), (3, 3)),
 ((2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2)),
 ((3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3)),
 ((3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3)),
 ((3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3)),
 ((3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3)),
 ((3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)),
 ((3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)),
 ((3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2)),
 ((3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((3, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1)),
 ((3, 3), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1)),
 ((3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1))
\end{equation}

Best Regards,
Pablo

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! how to read these notations ?

Comment: each permutation is the image of $X\times X$ in the lexicographical order.